# Trying to mock a method with int parameter but Mockito fails

Tags: mockito

I want to simulate the response of the following method:

```
public JobResult getJobResult(String jobId, int pageSize, String cursor)
```

The following way:

```
when(analyticsApi.getJobResult(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(jobResult);
```

But Mockito fails with the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of
> "org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any()" is null

Answer (score 10):

Turns out you cannot put any() on int parameters, so you have to mock it the following way:

```
when(analyticsApi.getJobResult(any(), anyInt(), any())).thenReturn(jobResult);
```